# Is it safe to delete "Tencent/MicroMsg/diskcache" folder?

Tags: samsung, files, wechat

Is it ok to delete Tencent - MicroMsg - diskcache folder in Samsung Galaxy S3? It's related to WeChat.

Answer (score 2):

To be short, it's sade to clear and remove `SD/Tencent/MicroMsg/diskcache`
The content of it is caches for chat pictures and Moments pictures that you have **sent**, so you can safely remove them. However if you go on to **send** pictures, things will re-generate in it. You might want to clean it up regularly.

Answer (score 0):

If you're referring to the ***Tencent*** cache folders from an app and not the ***Tencent virus,*** you're more than welcome to delete it, but it may re-appear.